# Microsoft SQL Server connect with Tableau

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I am trying to connect SQL Server data base with tableau cloud and I get this error in the photo, I checked SQL Server Manager. I make the TCP enabled, the name of the server is right, I don't know what can be the problem?

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Images can't be googled. If you google the actual error message `A network-related or instance.....` you'll find there are duplicate questions already. The error is saying that Tableau can't even find SQL Server

Comment: See if it helps: https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/error-login-timeout-expired-when-refreshing-extract-with-bridge

Comment: `with tableau cloud` a cloud service can't connect to an on-premise machine without a VPN or a bridge. The name `desktopblah` is interpreted as a local machine name on the *cloud* environment. Have you installed Tableau Bridge?